# Using modules in Fortran: Undefined reference to `parse_'

Tags: c, fortran, ipc

I am trying to use [the parse routine described here](http://gbenthien.net/strings/Strings.pdf) to parse a string in Fortran90. When following the link in the document one can [download a .zip with two f90-files](http://www.gbenthien.net/strings/Strings.zip), which I have done. I have then compiled them `gfortran -c precmod.f90 && gfortran -c stringmod.f90`. I have also added `use strings` to my program.

Despite of this, I receive the following error when compiling (`gfortran stringmod.o precmod.o calcs.o server.o`):

```
calcs.o: In function `calculate_':
calcs.f90:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `parse_'
collect2: error: ld returned exit status 1
```

calcs.f90 is shown below and server.o is a server written in C that should be invoked by calcs.

```
program name
use strings
use iso_c_binding, only: C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR, C_INT

implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    character(255) query
    integer calc, ans, portnum, calculate

    interface
        subroutine server(portnum) bind(C, name="server")
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
            integer(kind=c_int), value :: portnum
        end subroutine server
    end interface

    ! executable statements
    print *, "Please provide me with a port number. Plz. <3"
    read "(1i9)", portnum
    call server(portnum)

end program name

function calculate(query)
implicit none

    character(255) query, op
    integer length, i, calculate
    integer, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: inputarray

    call parse(query, ' ', inputarray, length)

    do i=1,size(inputarray)
        print *, inputarray(i, 1)
    end do

    calculate = 5

end function calculate
```

I have tried to add `public` to the top of stringmod.f90.

Comment: Is `parse` a procedure in the module `strings` (which isn't `use`d in the function `calculate`)?

Comment: @francescalus, parse is a procedure in the module strings - yes.

Comment: So the problem is, as francescalus says, that you haven't used the strings module in your function calculate, and so there isn't a parse subprogram in scope

Comment: @IanBush, oh, you have to declare the use within the function? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, or contain the function in the main program as then parse is in scope by host association, PLUS you make sure there is also an interface in scope for the function calculate at the invocation point. I much prefer this method. In general make sure you have an interface in scope for all your subprograms, modules are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have something like

```
program
end program

function func()
end function
```

then the function `func` is an *external function*, even when this is given in the same source code file as the main program.  This external function knows nothing about the main program, and in turn the main program knows little about the external function.

Part of this lack of knowledge is that, in the example of the question, the fact that the subroutine `parse` has an explicit interface (through the module) in the main program is irrelevant to `calculate`.

That is, the function `calculate` has its own scope and has no host.  To gain access to the module procedure `parse` it can itself use the module `strings`:

```
function calculate(query)
  use strings, only : parse
  implicit none
end function
```

There is a hint to this lack of being aware that `parse` is a module procedure in `strings`.  The name decoration in `parse_` (that single trailing underscore) is a common way to mangle an external procedure.  Module procedures (without `bind(c)`) generally have much more elaborate symbol names.

Finally, I'll repeat something from the comments.  Earlier, I said that the main program knows little about the external function.  In the main program we have the declaration

```
integer ... calculate
```

which says that the external function `calculate` (which has an implicit interface) has a return type of integer.  The function, in this case, could instead be made an internal function

```
program
  use strings, only : parse
 contains
  integer function calculate
  end function
end program
```

and not only does the function `calculate` have an explicit interface (removing also the need for that return declaration in the main program) but it also has access to `parse` through host association.